# phpunit testing a custom api and backbone.js

Tags: php, api, rest, tdd, phpunit

I am teaching one of my friends how to program and we have been working on it for about a year.  I want to give him the task of building an REST json API in PHP and I want to build a front end to connect to use the api in backbone.js.  I want him to get into the habit of doing test driven development and he has successfully installed phpunit in his machine.

My question is, how should he test his code if he is going to be returning json and I will be consuming it by using curl.  For this one, I will probably write all the tests first and let him build off those.  Should I write the tests to use curl to access the api and do asserts against his json return?  To me that seems like the way to go because I wouldn't have to know the names of his models or any other files before I write my tests.  I could just say here is what I want when I go to this url.  Is that a feasible way to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want him to write unit tests, I think he should mock the Request (GET and POST params) and test that the generated data is correct.
You don't need to do real CURL requests, not even JSON-encoding the data as those are tasks that can (and should) be put in different code layers.

Then you can write functional tests by doing real CURL calls to see if the data generation, encoding and transfer layers are correctly integrated.

Comment: Thanks, I will write tests for him to guide him in building his models.  Then I will write tests for myself against my backbone.sync calls.